# Is there any way to rename WordPress directory name to xyz

Tags: wordpress

I am trying WordPress in my localhost, can I rename the `http:/localhost/wordpress` to `http:/localhost/xyz`.

I am using Xampp server for this. I tried changing the Home and site url from `http:/localhost/wordpress` to `http:/localhost/xyz`, but only home page gets displayed bt other pages did not get displayed.

Like in homepage I have section for various products when I click on that I did give me error when I change the site and home url.

Is there any solution ?

Comment: Did you regenerate your permalinks, by saving them again?

Comment: how to regeneraate permalinks ?

Comment: by going into settings->permalinks and saving them again.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed WordPress with the URL http://localhost/wordpress, this is what you have on your database, you should connect to your MySQL server and do a Search / Replace of the old URL to update it to the new one, so search for

```
http://localhost/wordpress
```

and replace with

```
http://localhost/xyz
```

With this change you should see your website working again

Comment: can you clearify this bit please

Comment: Hello @TanviGhag if you're using Xampp you'll have an MySQL server too running, so check if you can access it with PhpMyAdmin (shipped with xammp) once there you'll need to search and replace the URLs, check this [link](https://betterstudio.com/blog/search-and-replace-phpmyadmin/)